Error in Dash Python trying to populate a Dropdown. Invalid argument options passed into Dropdown with ID “select_st”. Expected one of type [object]
The code for the Dropdown looks like this:
dcc.Dropdown(id='select_st',
             options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in states],
             value='FL',
             style={
                 'width':'80%', 
                 'padding':'3px', 
                 'font-size':'20px', 
                 'text-align':'left'})

states is a list whose contents are:

[‘AL’, ‘AR’, ‘AZ’, ‘CA’, ‘CO’, ‘CT’, ‘DC’, ‘DE’, ‘FL’, ‘GA’, ‘IA’, ‘ID’, ‘IL’, ‘IN’, ‘KS’, ‘KY’, ‘LA’, ‘MA’, ‘MD’, ‘ME’, ‘MI’, ‘MN’, ‘MO’, ‘MS’, ‘MT’, ‘NC’, ‘ND’, ‘NE’, ‘NH’, ‘NJ’, ‘NM’, ‘NV’, ‘NY’, ‘OH’, ‘OK’, ‘OR’, ‘PA’, ‘RI’, ‘SC’, ‘SD’, ‘TN’, ‘TX’, ‘UT’, ‘VA’, ‘VT’, ‘WA’, ‘WI’, ‘WV’, ‘WY’, ]

The error looks like this:

Invalid argument options passed into Dropdown with ID “select_st”.
Expected one of type [object].
Value provided:
[
{
“label”: “AL”,
“value”: “AL”
},
{
“label”: “AR”,
“value”: “AR”
},
{
“label”: “AZ”,
“value”: “AZ”
},
{
“label”: “CA”,
“value”: “CA”
},
{
“label”: “CO”,
“value”: “CO”
},
{
“label”: “CT”,
“value”: “CT”
},
{
“label”: “DC”,
“value”: “DC”
},
{
“label”: “DE”,
“value”: “DE”
},
{
“label”: “FL”,
“value”: “FL”
},
{
“label”: “GA”,
“value”: “GA”
},
{
“label”: “IA”,
“value”: “IA”
},
{
“label”: “ID”,
“value”: “ID”
},
{
“label”: “IL”,
“value”: “IL”
},
{
“label”: “IN”,
“value”: “IN”
},
{
“label”: “KS”,
“value”: “KS”
},
{
“label”: “KY”,
“value”: “KY”
},
{
“label”: “LA”,
“value”: “LA”
},
{
“label”: “MA”,
“value”: “MA”
},
{
“label”: “MD”,
“value”: “MD”
},
{
“label”: “ME”,
“value”: “ME”
},
{
“label”: “MI”,
“value”: “MI”
},
{
“label”: “MN”,
“value”: “MN”
},
{
“label”: “MO”,
“value”: “MO”
},
{
“label”: “MS”,
“value”: “MS”
},
{
“label”: “MT”,
“value”: “MT”
},
{
“label”: “NC”,
“value”: “NC”
},
{
“label”: “ND”,
“value”: “ND”
},
{
“label”: “NE”,
“value”: “NE”
},
{
“label”: “NH”,
“value”: “NH”
},
{
“label”: “NJ”,
“value”: “NJ”
},
{
“label”: “NM”,
“value”: “NM”
},
{
“label”: “NV”,
“value”: “NV”
},
{
“label”: “NY”,
“value”: “NY”
},
{
“label”: “OH”,
“value”: “OH”
},
{
“label”: “OK”,
“value”: “OK”
},
{
“label”: “OR”,
“value”: “OR”
},
{
“label”: “PA”,
“value”: “PA”
},
{
“label”: “RI”,
“value”: “RI”
},
{
“label”: “SC”,
“value”: “SC”
},
{
“label”: “SD”,
“value”: “SD”
},
{
“label”: “TN”,
“value”: “TN”
},
{
“label”: “TX”,
“value”: “TX”
},
{
“label”: “UT”,
“value”: “UT”
},
{
“label”: “VA”,
“value”: “VA”
},
{
“label”: “VT”,
“value”: “VT”
},
{
“label”: “WA”,
“value”: “WA”
},
{
“label”: “WI”,
“value”: “WI”
},
{
“label”: “WV”,
“value”: “WV”
},
{
“label”: “WY”,
“value”: “WY”
},
{
“label”: null,
“value”: null
}
]

This code used to work about a year ago and seems like it should still work, but I can’t quite figure out where it is going wrong.

Since the error says { “label”: null, “value”: null } in the last list entry, I assume the issue is due to the comma after the last state ‘WY’ on your list.
While I couldn’t replicate the same error on my machine, I believe removing the extraneous comma , or anything similar causing the null entries will resolve the issue.

Eliminating the null value at the end did the trick.  Thank You so much.

That's good to hear!
